# Using a terms query to list matching words in a document using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to index documents (PDF, Word, etc) using the Attachment Type plugin. Is it possible to query each document with a list of terms and have Elasticsearch return just the terms that match in the given document?

For example, I have a query that uses bool to enforce the query against a single document by id and a terms query which contains a list of terms that I want to check are matched in the document:

```
{
  query:{
    filtered: {
      query:{
        bool: {
          must: [{match: {_id: id}}]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        terms: {
          attachment: terms
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to somehow use this query so that I pass the terms ['apple', 'wood', 'pen', 'paper', 'window'] to a document with id 1 and Elasticsearch will return just the matching terms in document 1 (e.g. 'paper', 'wood'). NOTE: In reality, the number of terms that I want to check against each document is quite large - in the 1000's

Comment: I don't think that's possible. At most, you could use highlighting to see which matched in various fields, but I don't see an easier way. Another idea would be to give each term a constant score and to make a sum with all those that matched, but this is not feasible for thousands of terms.

Comment: Thank you Andrei. I am a bit surprised that it's not possible to ask ES something like "given this word list, which appear in this document?" Is it possible to get the Inverted Index for a document perhaps? Then I could do a union between my tag list and that...